# Left join multiple IList<> using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, repository

i have basically a post repository that should return all the  gallery items belong to it. If there's no gallery belonging to post it should still return post distinct by post id

```
public List<PostLocalizedOutput> GetAllPostsWithCategories(string culture, bool? isPublished)
    {
        var query =
                from p in Context.Posts
                join pl in Context.PostsLocalized on p.Id equals pl.PostId
                from c in p.Categories
                join cl in Context.CategoriesLocalized on c.Id equals cl.CategoryId
                from g in p.Galleries.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join gi in Context.GalleryItems on g.Id equals gi.GalleryId 


                where
                  pl.Culture == culture &&
                  cl.Culture == culture
                select new PostLocalizedOutput
                {
                    PostId = pl.PostId,
                    CategoryId = cl.CategoryId,
                    Title = pl.Title,
                    FormattedCategoryName = cl.FormattedCategoryName,
                    PostContent = pl.PostContent,
                    PostType = pl.Post.PostType,
                    IOrder = pl.Post.IOrder,
                    Tags = pl.Tags,
                    PublishDate = pl.Post.PublishDate,
                    ViewCount = pl.Post.ViewCount,
                    ShowInHomePageSlider = pl.Post.ShowInHomePageSlider,
                    AllowComments = pl.Post.AllowComments,
                    Image = pl.Post.Image,
                    IsArchived = pl.Post.IsArchived,
                    IsDraft = pl.Post.IsDraft,
                    IsPublished = pl.Post.IsPublished,
                    GalleryItems = new GalleryItemOutput
                    {
                        FileName = gi.FileName,
                        GalleryId = gi.GalleryId,
                        Id = gi.Id,
                        Notes = gi.Notes,
                        Title = gi.Title
                    } (around here i feel like i should foreach something or what?)
                };

        return query.OrderBy(x => x.IOrder).ThenBy(x => x.PublishDate).DistinctBy(x => x.PostId).ToList();
    }
```

here is my postlocalizedoutput

```
public class PostLocalizedOutput : IOutputDto
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    ...  
    public List<GalleryItemOutput> GalleryItems { get; set; }

}
```

GalleryItemOutput should be list because i want all the galleryitems of a post. But when i define it as a list in repository i cannot set each field of galleryitem of a post. This code now returns me four rows because i have four gallery items of that post and each one has the same postId. I do not want that. DefaultIfEmpty also does not work even if a post does not have any gallery items i should still be able to get that post without gallery items.

Any approach ?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you need a group-by on the post id?

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() does not work either. I need all posts even if a post does not have any galleryitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started.
Don’t know if this compiles, please just interpret as pseudo-code. Looks like your top-level range variable is PostsLocalized not Posts. This code assume/uses navigation properties that are probably setup in your EDM classes. I have overused let keyword here just to make it clearer for you. In the select new clause you can change the p1.Post.... to just p. I left them to make as few edits as possible.

```
var query =
        from pl in Context.PostsLocalized
        where pl.Culture == culture
        let p = p1.Post
        let categories = p.Categories
        let localizedCategories = categories.SelectMany(cat => cat.CategoriesLocalized).Where(cl => cl.Culture == culture)
        let galleries = p.Galleries
        let galleryItems = galleries.SelectMany(gal => gal.GalleryItems)
        let cl = localizedCategories.FirstOrDefault() // only one or zero of these i assume?

        select new PostLocalizedOutput
        {
            PostId = p1.PostId,
            CategoryId = cl.CategoryId, 
            Title = pl.Title,
            FormattedCategoryName = cl.FormattedCategoryName,
            PostContent = pl.PostContent,
            PostType = pl.Post.PostType,
            IOrder = pl.Post.IOrder,
            Tags = pl.Tags,
            PublishDate = pl.Post.PublishDate,
            ViewCount = pl.Post.ViewCount,
            ShowInHomePageSlider = pl.Post.ShowInHomePageSlider,
            AllowComments = pl.Post.AllowComments,
            Image = pl.Post.Image,
            IsArchived = pl.Post.IsArchived,
            IsDraft = pl.Post.IsDraft,
            IsPublished = pl.Post.IsPublished,

            GalleryItems = galleryItems.Select(gi => new GalleryItemOutput
            {
                FileName = gi.FileName,
                GalleryId = gi.GalleryId,
                Id = gi.Id,
                Notes = gi.Notes,
                Title = gi.Title
                })
// might need a .ToList() here on those GalleryItems

 (around here i feel like i should foreach something or what?)
            };
```

Comment: galleryItems here covers only gallery not galleryitems so i cannot set filename or any other fields of galleryitems

Comment: See edits. I think I interpreted your comment correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciated it. I now can get all posts whether it has galleryitem(as list) or not. a few optimizations left to cover here like  "there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first" .